# Training and Validation Loss Graph Meaning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

This is my first attempt at creating a LSTM RNN. I am confused about the meaning of the Training Loss & Validation Loss graphs I have generated. Here is an image of the graph:

[Training and Validation Loss Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX4hQ.jpg)

Here is a sample of the training data:

```
                        lat         long    trip_id mode_cat
datetime            id              
2011-08-27 06:13:01 20  39.979973   116.305745  1   1
2011-08-27 06:13:02 20  39.979957   116.305688  1   1
2011-08-27 06:13:03 20  39.979960   116.305693  1   1
2011-08-27 06:13:04 20  39.979970   116.305717  1   1
2011-08-27 06:13:05 20  39.979985   116.305732  1   1
```

Datetime and Id (user_id) are set as indices.

Here is the code for creating the moving window and the LSTM:

```
def moving_window(dataset_x, dataset_y, past_history):
    data, labels = [], []
    for i in range(past_history, len(dataset_x)):
        indices = range(i-past_history, i)
        data.append(dataset_x[indices])
        labels.append(dataset_y[i])
    return np.array(data), np.array(labels)

past_history = 60

x_train_single, y_train_single = moving_window(dataset_train_x, dataset_train_y, past_history)
x_test_single, y_test_single = moving_window(dataset_test_x, dataset_test_y, past_history)

buffer_size = len(x_train_single)//10
batch_size = 256

train_data_single = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train_single, y_train_single))
train_data_single = train_data_single.cache().shuffle(buffer_size).batch(batch_size).repeat()

test_data_single = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test_single, y_test_single))
test_data_single = test_data_single.batch(batch_size).repeat()

single_step_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
single_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32,
                                           input_shape=x_train_single.shape[-2:]))
single_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

single_step_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(), loss='mae')

evaluation_interval = len(x_train_single)//batch_size
epochs = 10

single_step_history = single_step_model.fit(train_data_single, epochs=epochs,
                                            steps_per_epoch=evaluation_interval,
                                            validation_data=test_data_single,
                                            validation_steps=50)
```

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  "I'm confused" is not a problem specification.  Training loss and validation loss are documented quite well in many places.  We need you to post your graphs and explain exactly how you're confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the gap between training loss and validation loss is large its means that your model is overfitting and if training loss is large its means your model is underfitting.
If your training loss and validation loss are overlapping or close to each other means your model is now good for prediction.

Here the model is overfitted

[image]